# crear un componente en React, el cual permita subir archivos y estos se pinten en una tabla

Tags: reactjs

A partir de este código, se puedo buscar en local un archivo y subirlo, pero necesito que este que quede en una tabla y desde esta se pueda eliminar:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


    <div>
     <span class="button-carga-principal btn-file">
      <h3>Agregar TAC</h3>
      <input type="file" />
     </span>
</div>


    <div class="tabla">
     <p class="titulo-tabla">Listado de TAC</p>
      <table class="table">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th scope="col" class="titulo-tableta">
          TAC
         </th>
         <th scope="col" class="titulo-tableta">
          Acciones
         </th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sin datos</th>
        <th scope="row">Sin datos</th>
       </tr>
        <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sin datos</th>
        <th scope="row">Sin datos</th>
       </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
    </div>
  </>
```

Como podran observar el archivo carga, pero necesito que este se cargue en el campo que dice "sin datos" en el encabezado de TAC y en otro campo que tuviera una opción de eliminarlo.

Comment: Muy bien, sugiero que compartas un [Ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has intentado para que algún colega de la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Saludos

Comment: Cordial saludo, realice los cambios con un ejemplo

Comment: ¿Qué clase de archivos necesitas subir? ¿Y qué datos específicos se deben mostrar en la tabla?

Comment: Como puedes validar en el ejemplo mínimo verificable que me solicitaron, cuando se busca cargar un tipo de archivo, este muestra el nombre del archivo con su respectiva extensión, ese mismo dato necesite que se pinte es en la tabla y que en el otro campo hubiera una opción de eliminar este documento. Los tipos de archivos serian, pfd, excel, jpg. Gracias